# Parsing PDF with python fails on cssselect

Tags: python, pdf, xpath

Trying to parse a PDF file with pdfquery, PDFDocument and PDFParser.
Also tried pdfquery sample code.
Alwyas getting error from cssselect/parser.py

> SelectorSyntaxError: Expected string or ident

Tried upgrading cssselect, didnt work.

Anyone has a clue?
I'm running Python 2.7

Im using code and sample file from: https://github.com/jcushman/pdfquery

```
pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery("tests/samples/IRS_1040A.pdf")
pdf.extract( [
 ('with_parent','LTPage[pageid=1]'),
 ('with_formatter', 'text'),
 ('last_name', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("315,680,395,700")'),
 ('spouse', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("170,650,220,680")'),
 ('with_parent','LTPage[pageid=2]'),
 ('oath', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:contains("perjury")', lambda match: match.text()[:30]+"..."),
 ('year', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:contains("Form 1040A (")', lambda match: int(match.text()[-5:-1]))
])
```

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: It would be help to provide a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, added the code, cant attach sample file, however is in github link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the examples and it seems you're missing some quotation marks (in the xpath expressions `LTPage[pageid="1"]` and `LTPage[pageid="2"]`. With the quotes there's no error message.

```
pdf.extract( [
 ('with_parent','LTPage[pageid="1"]'),
 ('with_formatter', 'text'),
 ('last_name', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("315,680,395,700")'),
 ('spouse', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("170,650,220,680")'),
 ('with_parent','LTPage[pageid="2"]'),
 ('oath', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:contains("perjury")', lambda match: match.text()[:30]+"..."),
 ('year', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:contains("Form 1040A (")', lambda match: int(match.text()[-5:-1]))
])
```

Comment: Thank you. Which is missed in their documentation itself.